# React + Typescript: set "multilevel" interface' props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Good day everyone!

We have react-component ClassWithMyData which contains "filter" as one of it's props. In it's turn, "filter" is an instance of lists.ClassWithMyDataFilter interface.

```
interface StateProps {
     filter: lists.ClassWithMyDataFilter;
}

interface StoreProps {
     clearFilter: () => void;
}

class ClassWithMyData extends React.Component<StoteProps & StateProps, {}> {

}

export interface ClassWithMyDataFilter {
      attrs: api.ClassWithMyDataFilterAttrs
}
```

interface ClassWithMyDataFilter contains "attrs" - an instance of ClassWithMyDataFilterAttrs interface;

```
export interface ClassWithMyDataFilterAttrs {
      code: string;
      name: string;
}
```

The task is to set "name" and "code" in  this.ptops.filter.attrs to empty string "" with clearFilter() function.
Now I'm doing it this way:

```
private clearFilter = () => {

 this.props.filter.attrs.code = "";
 this.props.filter.attrs.name = "";
 this.props.updateFilter (this.props.filter);

}
```

but is there a way to avoid directly props setting inside function? The questions and answers which i found before covered only "one-interface-inside-class" cases. But how can I correctly set `this.props.interface1.interface2.value`?

Thank you in advance, and excuse me if I confused the terms.

Comment: 1. Why do you thing it is a bad practice? 2. Why do you use `private clearFilter = () => {` instead of `private clearFilter() {`? 3. You have million of typos 4. `ClassWithMyDataFilterAttrs` is not a class but an `interface` which are absolutely different things. Please edit your question to be more understandable, narrow down the amount of the code and show only relevant things you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

[Props are read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only) and you shouldn't mutate the objects

Your code should be:

```
private clearFilter = () => {
 this.props.updateFilter ({attrs:{code:"", name:""}});
}
```

Or if you need to call with other properties on `attrs` you can use the spread operator:

```
private clearFilter = () => {
  this.props.updateFilter ({attrs:{...this.props.filter.attrs, code:"", name:""}});
}
```

Generally you need to create every object in the hierarchy:

```
cont newInterface1 = {...interface1, interface2:{...interface1.interface2, value:"newValue"}}
```

You can also use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) library

Comment: Thanx for the answer! But this.props.updateFilter() in my code takes this.props.filter as attribute; does is correct to call it with {attrs:{code:"", name:""}}?